# Is it possible to include only the part of jQuery Mobile library which is being used?

Tags: jquery, css, optimization, jquery-mobile

In jQuery UI we can exclude the effect which we don't need and can make the lightweight library for project. see here http://jqueryui.com/download

For jQuery mobile http://jquerymobile.com/download/ this facility is not available. But can i exclude the part from library which I don't want to make the library lightweight.

By default jquery mobile add

```
jQuery core, 31KB as we've seen
jQuery Mobile specific code, 20KB
CSS rules, 7KB
images, 14.1KB
```

I also want to remove unneeded things from CSS too because by default jQuery has 5 different themes.

Comment: +1 for idea, you should suggest it to jQuery Mobile devs. It'd definitely be a lot better to be able to get read of unused script/styles.  See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582083

Answer (score 1):

As of the jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 release, they now offer a download builder that allows you to only download what you want.

Learn More: http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: In my experience, it the "builder" did something to reduce the size of the CSS files, but I don't know if it eliminated _everything_ that I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole build setup from github, remove widgets you don't need trom the manifest and build it then.

On linux - just use `make`

On Windows - you'll have to run the PHP build script