# Use part jQuery mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, web-frameworks

I would like to use widgets from jQuery Mobile - buttons, drop down list, etc.

I already have a site that has been developed without the use of jQuery mobile, which has its own menus and links - and when I try to add jQuery mobile framework to it, it causes all sorts of problems (overrides CSS, tries to hijack page transitions, etc).

Is it possible to disable some features of the framework?

This is related to the question: [Removing unused jQuery Mobile elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582083/removing-unused-jquery-mobile-elements) - but it deals with minimizing the script size. I only want to disable certain functinality, so it doesnt interfere with the rest of my app.

Update: Part of the problem caused by using jQuery Mobile "as is" stems from the fact that it will attempt to load all links via ajax. It can be mitigated by adding

```
rel="external"
```

to links, so jQM won't attempt to load it via ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a builder for JQM coming soon. As of 5/4/2012 its still in beta. Hang in there and the feature will be available any time now. I will try to update this answer when its released.

**Update** here is a link to the JQM builder http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Answer (score 1):

Adding the data-role="none" attribute to any form or button element tells the framework to not apply any enhanced styles or scripting

Answer (score 1):

Building your package with only needed components is the first step that you should do but sometimes it is not enough.

There is also a piece of code which we found recently and used to stop loading jQuery Mobile panes on one page. This is very usefull if you want to use jQuery Mobile components separately without the framework itself. In other words, you still want to have a normal page behaviour (i.e. page reloads by clicking links) and use some jQuery Mobile components.

And here is this code that did a trick for our Symfony 2 project:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).bind('mobileinit',function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  });
})(jQuery);
```